# Removing Alphabetic Characters from a String

Tags: javascript, string, character, google-apps, alphabetic

I need to remove the "`ML`" portion of "`ML 11/07`" but I want to keep the numbers as well as the slash.

Here is my current code (Google Apps Script)

```
var sec=second.replace("[^\\d.]", "");
tss.getRange(counter2, 5).setValue(sec);
```

Comment: `second.substr(3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` `/[a-z]/ig`, `.trim()`

```
var sec = second.replace(/[a-z]/ig, "").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
var string = "ML 11/07"
var result = string.split(" ");

console.log(result[1]);
```